# Fluent bit to es: create dynamic index pattern based on timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, devops, fluent-bit

I'm trying to create a dynamic index pattern based on timestamp, while sending logs from fluentbit to es, but unable to create an index pattern with a timestamp like `(dev-2022-07-14)`. Below is my output section of `fb-configmap.yaml` file.

```
filter-kubernetes.conf: |
[FILTER]
    Name                kubernetes
    Match               kube.*
    Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
    Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
    Merge_Log           On
    Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
    K8S-Logging.Parser  On
    K8S-Logging.Exclude Off

output-elasticsearch.conf: |
[OUTPUT]
    Name            es
    Match           *
    Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
    Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
    HTTP_User       ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER}
    HTTP_Passwd     ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWD}
    Logstash_Format On
    Logstash_Prefix dev-%Y%M%D
    Time_Key        @timestamp
    Generate_ID     On
    Include_Tag_Key On
    Replace_Dots    On
    Retry_Limit     False
    Buffer_Size     False
    tls             On
    tls.verify      Off
```

Here, when I'm trying without a timestamp, it's creating an index pattern as `dev`. I've added the above code for timestamp, it stops sending logs to es.
But, I'm expecting the index pattern like `dev-2022-07-14` `dev-2022-07-15`